# PHP select query has no bound

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, join

I am trying to do a query onto my database with the following code.

```
public function getFreeFields($date){
        print_r($date);
        $db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
    $select = $db->select()
        ->from(array('f' => $this->_tablename()), array('f.fie_id','f.fie_name'))
                    ->join('reservation','reservation.res_field = f.fie_id')
                    ->where('reservation.res_date_from > ?'. $date)
                    ->where('reservation.res_date_till < ?'. $date);

    $result = $db->fetchRow($select);
    $data = $this->_mapper->toObject( is_array($result) ? $result : array() );

    return $data;
    }
```

But it crashes with the following error.

```
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound'
```

When I die after the print_r, I got the correct date that I give to the request.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
->where('r.res_date_from > ?'. $date)
->where('r.res_date_till < ?'. $date);
```

to

```
->where('r.res_date_from > ?', $date)
->where('r.res_date_till < ?', $date);
```